# Azure kubernetes "The site can't be reached" when using URL in Chrome

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, url, kubernetes, ip

I'm a noob in setting up a running .Net Core app in Kubernetes, using Azure. I have a working 'dev' version of the app that I can successfully reach using its URL. I've deployed a production version of the app to a different pod within the cluster, but when I use the URL in Chrome that I expect to load my app, I see an error in Chrome "This site can't be reached" and ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. I'm using `http` (not `https`) in the URL, and I've tried entering the URL without any path, and also the URL plus a known path within the app.

When I ping the Url, it pings the correct IP. In Azure, under 'Public IP addresses', it shows the IP as associated with a load balancer. This load balancer is shared, and is also used for the 'dev' version of the app. The load balancer is showing dedicated backend pools (VM resources) for production, and has a load balancing rule that specifies connection using port 80. There's also an outbound rule that has the frontend IP address associated (as well as the frontend IP address used by dev).

I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-static-ip#create-an-ingress-route) to set up the ingress controller and ingress rules (but I didn't create an SSL certificate yet). I created an `ingress-prod` namespace, and using that namespace I can see the ingress controller running as a pod:

[image]

In the `ingress-basic` namespace (which shows the pods used by the dev instance), I see the following:

[image]

In the pod that contains my app, my app is running:

[image]

`kubectl get ing` using the same namespace that the app is running in shows me this:

```
NAME                            HOSTS                ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
cm-acme-http-solver-abcdef      myapp.mydomain.com             80        3d21h
myapp-ingress-rules             myapp.mydomain.com             80, 443   3d21h
```

`kubectl get deployments` in the same namespace shows me a deployment, and `kubectl get services` shows the following:

```
NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
cm-acme-http-solver-abc12   NodePort    (IP is shown)   <none>        8089:30212/TCP   3d21h
myapp-prod                  ClusterIP   (IP is shown)   <none>        5000/TCP         13d
```

What can I do to diagnose what the issue may be? Any ideas what may be the issue? Any ideas/suggestions are really appreciated!

Comment: Add logs from ingress controller pods. Add output of `kubectl describe svc myapp-prod `